# When space (or parentheses) are required in C during compilation?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I am learning how compilation works and my final goal is to write a mini C compiler. I am still at the beginning of this project. As I was working on the scanner and parser parts to build the AST, I realized that space is (or parentheses are) required in expressions like that `i+ +4`, `i+(+4)`, `i- -4`, or `i-(-4)`. Otherwise, in `i--4` expression (for example), `--` is interpreted as the unary operator `--` and an error is raised. I understand perfectly the reason. This is not the question.
 The question is the following, Before, I though naively that spaces were not so important in C if only for concerns of code readability. But now, I wonder if there are another examples like theses described above ?

Comment: Yes, for example you cannot write `intmain` or `return0`. It has to be `int main` / `return 0` or `int(main)` / `return(0)`.

Comment: I agree with these obvious examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for when spaces are needed in C are not specified explicitly but are consequences of how C is parsed. The rules for this are fairly complicated, as they involve multiple phases of analysis and some exceptions for various situations. If you are writing a C compiler, you need to be using the C standard as a reference.

C 2018 5.1.1.2 specifies translation phases (rephrasing and summarizing, not exact quotes):

1. Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped to the source character set. Trigraph sequences are replaced by single-character representations.
2. Lines continued with backslashes are merged.
3. The source file is converted from characters into preprocessing tokens and white-space characters—each sequence of characters that can be a preprocessing token is converted to a preprocessing token, and each comment becomes one space.
4. Preprocessing is performed (directives are executed and macros are expanded).
5. Source characters in character constants and string literals are converted to members of the execution character set.
6. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.
7. White-space characters are discarded. “Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.” (That quoted text is the main part of C compilation as we think of it!)
8. The program is linked to become an executable file.

Primarily, where spaces are needed in C source code is governed by phase 3, the formation of preprocessing tokens. This is specified in C 2018 6.4. A grammar for preprocessing tokens is given in paragraph 1 (more on this below), and paragraph 4 tells us:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token. There is one exception to this rule: header name preprocessing tokens are recognized only within `#include` preprocessing directives and in implementation-defined locations within `#pragma` directives. In such contexts, a sequence of characters that could be either a header name or a string literal is recognized as the former.

Paragraph 1 tells us a preprocessing token is one of a *header-name*, *identifier*, *pp-number*, *character-constant*, *string-literal*, *punctuator*, or a non-white-space character that is not one of the preceding items.

Then further subclauses in 6.4 tell us what those tokens look like.

Phase 3 induces two rules for where you need a space that are essentially:

- If the source code would be parsed, according to the above rules, as one preprocessing token where you want two, then you must insert a space where you want the first token to end.
- If using `/` and `*` other than as `/*` to introduce a comment, put a space between them.

Phase 4 induces another rule. Because 6.10.3 3 says “There shall be white space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro,” you need a space to distinguish a function-like macro:

```
#define foo(x) (3*(x)) // Macro that acts on argument x.
#define foo (x)        // Macro that expands to `(x)`.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to fix some old code and change

```
#define ALT_7      (0xfe+OFFSET)
```

to

```
#define ALT_7      (0xfe +OFFSET)
```

The reason being that `0xfe+OFFSET` is a *preprocessing number* token and not three tokens as one might naively think. The old compiler parsed it as three, but the new one failed because it parsed it as one which was not a valid numerical constant.

There's likely more on the preprocessor side of things, but it's more obscure (as the whole subject of C/C++ preprocessing).

Comment: This does not answer the question generally. It gives a single limited instance, and that is not enough to explain for C parsing generally, and it does not explain the instance (as by explaining how it fits into C parsing or is specified by the standard).

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are indeed required in many situations:

- Macro definitions:

  ```
  #define MACRO (a)      // defines a simple macro, it expands to (a)
  #define MACRO(a)       // defines a function-like macro with a single parameter a
  ```
- Comment syntax gotcha:

  ```
  a/*b    // starts a comment */
  a/ *b   // a divided by the value pointed to by b
  ```
- Preprocessing number literals:

  ```
  0x2e+1  <>  0x2e +1
  ```
- Similar problem with trigraphs:

  ```
  "??/??/????"  <>  "??" "/??" "/????"  // "??/??/????" is parsed as "\\????"
  ```
- Token separation:

  ```
  a+ +b   <>  a++b   // a++b would be a syntax error
  a- -b   <>  a--b   // a--b would be a syntax error
  a& &b   <>  a&&b   // but &b is unlikely to be a valid operand for &
  ```
- C++ nested template problem:

  ```
  template a<b<c> >
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Lexers in most langugages are based on greedy regexes — a token is as long as it can be.

If ++ can be interpreted as the `++` operator (from left to right) it won't be lexed as two pluses. If `inta` can be interpreted as an identifier, it won't be interpreted as `int` followed by `a`, etc.

`i+ +4` needs a whitespace, a parenthesis, or something in between the `+` and `+` or else the lexer will greedily consume it from left to right as `++`.

Comment: This is not a useful answer because it uses jargon without explaining it: “Lexers,” “regexes,” “hungry,” “token.” Also, it does not give any information that could resolve whether `++` “can be interpreted” as `++`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is not exactly the question. I wrote I understand why it is interpreted like that. The question concerns the existence of another examples that I should be aware of.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This question is tagged `flex-lexer`, so saying the term "lexer" needs to be explained is like saying that an answer to a Java question needs to first explain what Java is. I'd argue that the same goes for regular expressions (as they're a concept fundamental to `flex`). And "hungry" is explained in the same sentence where it's used: "a token is as long as it can be" (though I've never heard that term and think that it's probably a mistranslation of "greedy").

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to a C compiler, the question is: Which are you implementing?

The C preprocessor actually generates a token for whitespace and uses that to determine things. If you are implementing a combined preprocessor/compiler, you may want to do that tokenizing only once and then throw away the whitespace tokens before handing the token stream off to the compiler proper.

C itself seems to concern itself mostly with spaces, tabs and line breaks as indicators of the end of a token.

Beyond that, it also has the concept of one- or two-character operators, and seems to greedily match them. That is, `- -` gets turned into `MINUS_TOKEN, MINUS_TOKEN`, whereas `--` no matter where, always gets turned into `DECREMENT`.

That is, your example of `i--4` gives a parser error, as there is an extraneous `4` following the postfix-decrement operator.

So that proves that operators are matched greedily. Writing `i - -4` OTOH works, because the greedy matching sees the space as an end for the first `-` token, and starts a new one, which then yields a second minus.

In summary, C itself ignores whitespace beyond the tokenizing phase, the preprocessor does not.